# Passing Variables to Methods in CATVBA

Tags: vba, catia

This macro is written to manipulate features in CATIA. My macro asks the user to select a sketch so that it can then be copied into a new geometrical set (first stage of a much larger project). Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
Dim activeDoc As PartDocument
Set activeDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Dim part1 As Part
Set part1 = activeDoc.Part

Dim bodies1 As Bodies
Set bodies1 = part1.Bodies

Dim body1 As Body
Set body1 = bodies1.Item("PartBody")

Dim shapes1 As Shapes
Set shapes1 = body1.Shapes

Dim solid1 As Solid
Set solid1 = shapes1.Item("Combine.1")

Dim sketch1 As Sketch
```

---

```
Set sketch1 = solid1.GetItem(selectedSketch)
```

---

```
Dim selection1 As Selection
Set selection1 = activeDoc.Selection
selection1.clear

selection1.Add sketch1

etc...
```

The line of code within the horizontal lines is the subject of my conundrum. `selectedSketch` is a variable of type string holding a sketch name that is set earlier in the code via user selection.

I get the error:

> "Object doesn't support this action".

Coming from an VBA programming in Excel background, passing variables as method parameters is very easy. The V5automation.chm offers the only help that the method `GetItem` takes `CATBSTR IDName` as it's parameter. I'm guessing `CATBSTR` stands for string. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what you tried to do with `Set sketch1 = solid1.GetItem(selectedSketch)`, but that would certainly not work. If you already selected the sketch, why would you retrieve it again? If you want to copy your sketch, use the selection object, which is quite simple (Sel.add, Sel.copy, Sel.clear, Sel.add, Sel.Paste)

Comment: I am trying to find a solution to this as well. From what I have found out so far, `CATBSTR` is a `typedef` accessible to C++ developers through the System Framework header file. [This website](http://www.maruf.ca/files/caadoc/CAASysTechArticles/CAASysAutomationItf.htm) has some useful information. However, I haven't had any luck on getting it to work in VBA so far, I'll update if I do though.

Comment: @DevinTrowbridge if I remember correctly from my experiences, sketches are next to impossible to use in automation. I ended up finding a different, but ultimately more elegant solution to my specific problem. You're welcome to shoot me a private message and I'd be happy to help you out.